# How can I implement a configurable program data location for a C++ library installation using CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm using CMake to build a C++ static library, used by other internal dev teams in bigger projects. The library is available to the other teams as a GIT repository, which they can clone or include as submodule.

This library depends, at runtime, by a folder of files, containing some data. This folder needs to be located next to the main executable which is using the library.

I would like that any user of my library could use it by simply doing this in their `CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_subdirectory(<path-to-my-library>)
add_executable(BigExe <...>)
target_link_library(BigExe MyLibrary)
install(TARGETS BigExe)
```

The install directory should contain the `BigExe` binary file and then, right next to it, the folder with the data needed by my library.

How should the `install(...)` command look like in ther CMakeLists.txt of my library?

I'm also ready to accept a "broader" approach, involving a more deep restructuring of the way my library is distributed.

So far, the CMakeLists.txt of my library is something like this

```
add_library(MyLibrary STATIC <...>)

target_include_directories(MyLibrary 
    PUBLIC 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

target_compile_definitions(MyLibrary PUBLIC <...>)

install(DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/MyData" DESTINATION bin)
```

This solution works if and only if the `BigExe` is installed in the same `bin` subfolder, forcing the users of my library to follow the folder structure I chose. I would like to do the reverse: my library should place its things where its users place their things...

The library needs to be compiled for both Windows and Linux systems.

Comment: Can you try to provide configurable paths to that data in your library? That way you don't have to keep data in the same place as executable. Your library will expose an interface which will allow users setting path to that data.

Comment: of-topic: I would strongly suggest to use *.so over *.a to enable the OS team to care for use of new system libs as *.a will nail down the required system libs to the compile-time versions.

Answer (score 1):

> This library depends, at runtime, by a folder of files, containing some data. This folder needs to be located next to the main executable which is using the library.
>
> How should the install(...) command look like in ther CMakeLists.txt of my library?

So you are *not* installing your library, but some data files. Read https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-files

Typically, on Linux they go into `/usr/share/<library>/` if they are machine-independent files, or `/usr/lib/<library>/` if they are machine dependent files.

```
set(yourdatafiles ...)
install(
   FILES ${yourdatafiles}
   TYPE DATA
)
```

The program should open `/usr/share/yourlibrary/` and read from there.

Comment: How does this work on Windows?

Comment: Good question, I have no idea about windows, someone else will have to chime in.

Comment: This would also not maintain the folder tree of the original folder, right?

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-directories